# Setting a cookie that triggers a redirect

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

     <html>
     <head>
     <title>login test</title>
     <script>

        window.onload = iniAll;
     function iniAll(){
       document.getElementById("CLIENT").onclick = setCookie;

       var setCookie = function(exdays){
                var d = new Date();
                d.seTime(d.getTime() + (exdays *20*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
                documenet.cookie = Test = "=" + Test + "; "
                loadPageC();
            }


        var loadPageC = function(){

            window.location = "http://www.cnn.com";
            return false;
        }
            if (document.cookie === "Test = test"){

             return loadPageC;
            }
            else {
            }

     }
    </script> 
    </head>

    <body>
    <span style="text-align: center;"><h1>Make your choice.</h1></span>
     <a href="http://www.threepanelsoul.com" id="CLIENT">CLIENT</a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

here is the updated code however still neither the cookie is setting nor the redirect called by function loadPageC.   Komodo is telling me that iniAll will not always return a value.  What i want it to do is to check for a cookie either called reader/client or a value of reader/client, and depending of if it is a reader it will redirect it to the reader page and a client cookie to the client page.  The scirpt needed to have a an else function of just loading the login page in the absence of the cookie, I have striped that out in an effor to just get the cookie redirect to work.

Comment: Try using the browsers inbuilt development tools (F12)... or if you're using FireFox then I thoroughly recommend [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com).  That will quickly let you find exactly where syntax errors are in your client-side code

Comment: FYI: `window.onload = iniAll; window.onload = tasteBatter;` – that second statement overwrites the value you’ve set with the first one; assignments like this are not “additive”.

Comment: Oh ok So i should hang everything off of iniAll and make that the overall JS function for what i want to do?  Kicking myself for not thinking JS was the same as CSS and HTML where the last overwrites the first.

Comment: Maybe just a typo? In the example, in the setCookie function, you are calling "documenet.cookie" instead of "document.cookie".